# Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between object inspector and form designer?

Tags: delphi, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-xe7

You can go from the form designer to the object inspector to the source editor in a circle using the <kbd>F11</kbd> key:

Code -> Inspector -> Design -> Inspector -> Code -> Inspector -> ...

But most of the time when designing a form I only want:

Inspector <-> Design

I searched in the Delphi help and didn't find any suitable keyboard shortcut.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that does that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Enter</kbd> does exactly that. (It only took me about 10 years to figure that one out ...)

Some other useful keys:

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> navigates the controls in their `TabOrder` while the form designer is focused.
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between name and value in the object inspector while it is focused.
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> goes to the parent of the currently focused control in the form designer.

For all the other shortcuts see also (none of which lists <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the context of my question):

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts
- http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Default_IDE_Shortcut_Keys
- http://delphiblog.twodesk.com/quick-delphi-tips-form-designer-keyboard-shortcuts
- http://keencode.blogspot.de/2014/05/delphi-most-useful-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: @UweRaabe Sure, I did a search for keyboad shortcuts more than once, but it didn't come to mind to actually ask on the newsgroups / stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

If you are inside the inspector editing a property, you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to go to the Source of active form (another <kbd>F12</kbd> swich to design).

You can use also <kbd>F11</kbd>. Inside the property editor; <kbd>F11</kbd> do the sequence:

- Property  Editor
- Design
- Property  Editor
- Source
- Property  Editor
- ...